MudBlazor: is there a way to conditionally select high vs low density for component layout?
Back when UWP was all the rage, there was an update whereby the layout of native controls would automatically conform to high-density or low-density, depending on whether the app was being run on a tablet or Windows Phone, versus on the desktop.
I was wondering if the same could be done with MudBlazor (or Blazor WASM in general).
Essentially I just want to know if the user is interacting with the page with their finger (i.e. no mouse attached), and if so, use the normal low-density layout, like so:

Then in desktop scenarios (mouse & keyboard), collapse the bulk of the unnecessary margins for a more compact layout:

I understand that there are plenty of media queries built into MudBlazor, but that seems based solely on screen size, so that wouldn't be a suitable basis for selecting high-density. If the user had a giant tablet, I would still want low-density for touch operation.
Is this doable?

Assuming you could identify when a user has touch capability, would you also force a low-density mode for people who have a mouse attached to their tablet? What about a laptop with a touch screen?

Those are all valid questions, which I'm sure Microsoft and the UWP team considered when introducing that feature. So my first question would be, does MudBlazor already have this capability?

No, MudBlazor only checks screen size.
